# SQL Server Copy database to different server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to take a copy of a database into another server. I usually been making backup, copy the backup file to another server and restore it. But the backup is 90GB, and the space left after copying the backup to the destination folder is only 26GB. As you probably understand by now I'm not able to restore the database as it doesn't have enough space. So my question is is possible to restore database by replacing backup file? Any other suggestions? Increasing the disc space is not an option as this is just a testing server and the space will be enough after restoring. Thank you

Comment: You can shrink the database files on the original database before taking the backup and see how much memory that frees: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-file?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You could also try splitting the backup files into multiple files to help manage the load of 90G. Backup in multiple files: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/935/backup-to-multiple-files-for-faster-and-smaller-sql-server-files/ - Restore from multiple files: http://www.sqlideas.com/2012/02/restore-full-database-from-multiple.html

Comment: You could try restoring the database using the backup file stored on another server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-to-a-new-location-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Restore from multiple files will join files before restoring so no difference. Shrink database doesn't do anything as the database is really huge.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL Server version have you tried enabling compressing during backup. You would be surprised by how small the backup file can get after compression. Also if your database is set to SIMPLE recovery you could look to reduce the log file size before you backup.

You can find some steps on how to enable compression during backup here
https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-configure-backup-compression/